# Slope of a parametrically-defined curve

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, parametric, curves

> A curve has parametric equations
>
> $$x = t − \frac 1t \qquad\qquad\qquad y = 2t + \frac 1t$$
>
> with $t \ne 0$. Show that $$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x} = 2 - \frac{3}{t^2+1}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts about it? What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: stucked when trying to prove

Comment: Surely you must have tried **something**? We need to have some idea where you are stuck and exactly what you find difficult. Otherwise the answer could be anything from "that's obvious" to an overly detailed explanation - both would probably be a waste of time.

Comment: ok i tried and i got the answer thank you

Answer (score 2):

The chain rule tells us that $$\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} $$

We can easily calculate two of those derivatives, and then solve for the third.

Answer (score 2):

The hint:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y'_t}{x'_t}.$$